# Java ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, exception

when remove the second last element there is no ConcurrentModificationException

```
List<String> myList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(myList1, "str1","str2","str3","str4","str5");
for(String element : myList1){//no ConcurrentModificationException here
if(element.equalsIgnoreCase("str4"))
    myList1.remove("str4");
}
System.out.println(myList1);
```

But when remove other elements there is a ConcurrentModificationException

```
List<String> myList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(myList2, "str1","str2","str3","str4","str5");
for(String element : myList2){//ConcurrentModificationException here
if(element.equalsIgnoreCase("str1"))
    myList2.remove("str1");
}
System.out.println(myList2);
```

what is the reason?

Comment: Please read the question carefully guys.

Comment: In your first piece of code also there is error "Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException". You cannot update the same Collection when you are iterating over it.

Comment: Why I didn't get the Exception? Did you tried?

Comment: I tried with integers (10 elements) and have the same problem with the second element from the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm seeing the same thing,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Launcher 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        doThis();
        doThat();
    }

    private static void doThis()
    {
        System.out.println("dothis");
        try
        {
            List<String> myList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            Collections.addAll(myList1, "str1","str2","str3","str4","str5");
            for(String element : myList1){//no ConcurrentModificationException here
            if(element.equalsIgnoreCase("str4"))
                myList1.remove("str4");
            }
            System.out.println(myList1);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void doThat()
    {
        System.out.println("dothat");
        try
        {
            List<String> myList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            Collections.addAll(myList2, "str1","str2","str3","str4","str5");
            for(String element : myList2){//ConcurrentModificationException here
            if(element.equalsIgnoreCase("str1"))
                myList2.remove("str1");
            }
            System.out.println(myList2);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

which outputs,

```
dothis
[str1, str2, str3, str5]
dothat
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.foo.Launcher.doThat(Launcher.java:41)
    at com.foo.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:12)
```

---

And I've found [**the reason**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673653/why-isnt-this-code-causing-a-concurrentmodificationexception).

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean guys.

Comment: @user1947415, I've added a link which may prove useful.

Answer (score 3):

Java use a modCount(modification count) and an expectedCount to test whether there is a modification to the list.

```
final void checkForComodification() {
    if (modCount != expectedModCount)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
}
```

In both condition, modCount is 6 after the remove, but expectedModCount is 5.

The problem is the hasNext().

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    return cursor != size;
}
```

The list use a cursor and size to check whether has a next element. And the hasNext() is happend before the checkForComodification because the checkForComodification() is called in the next() method.

```
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return cursor != size;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E next() {
        checkForComodification();
        int i = cursor;
        if (i >= size)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
        if (i >= elementData.length)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        cursor = i + 1;
        return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
    }
```

So when you remove the second last element, the cursor=4, and size=4 also. hasNext() return false. Jump out of the loop and print the result.

Comment: But, my point is, the only difference between two pieces of code is that the first one remove the "str4" while the second one remove "str1". But, the first one run successfully. The second one throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: This is exactly the reason why it failed when you removed second element. +1 Jermaine Xu

Answer (score 2):

The actual code that javac builds for `for-each` is

```
    Iterator<String> i = myList1.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        String element = i.next();
        if (element.equalsIgnoreCase("str4"))
            myList1.remove("str4");
    }
```

and this is ArrayList Iterator.hasNext implementation

```
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return cursor != size;
    }
```

as we can see `hasNext()` does not check for concurrent modification so when we remove the last but one element the loop ends without noticing the the problem.

Actually it is strange that `next()` and `remove()` check for concurrent modification but `hasNext()` does not. Fail-fast iterator is supposed to detect bugs, but our bug went unnoticed.

Answer (score -2):

This is a commonly occurring issue. StackOverflow has hundreds of threads covering this. You can find the answer to your question here:

[How can I iterate over an object while modifying it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517666/how-can-i-iterate-over-an-object-while-modifying-it-in-java?lq=1)

When you remove the second last element, The hasNext() check fails and the loop iteration stops. Check the ArrayList iterator code in JDK.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.Itr.hasNext%28%29

But in case of removal of second element the hasNext() check passes and you enter the next() method where the first thing it checks for is modification to the arrayList and hence the exception. Please check this code:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.Itr.next%28%29

The safest way is to remove the element using the iterators remove method.

Try **debugger** to step over the code, for a better understanding of how it works.

Comment: You didn't get me guys. I understand I need to use Iterator to remove element while iterate through it. But, my question is why the first piece of code didn't throw a ConcurrentModificationException as expect. I have test this only happens when you remove the second last element.

Comment: I have updated my answer, To understand these sort of issues Debugger is your best bet