# Why am I not getting a ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, for-loop, collections, concurrentmodification

I have an *EventBus* class to add/remove handler and dispatch an event to handlers:

```
public class EventBus{
  private Map<Integer,List<EventHandler>> handlers = new HashMap<>();
  private static EventBus ourInstance = new EventBus();

  public static EventBus getInstance(){
    return ourInstance;
  }

  public <T extends EventHandler> void fireEvent(Event<T> event){
    int hash = event.getAssociatedType().hashCode();
    List<EventHandler> handlersSublist = handlers.get(hash);
    if(handlersSublist != null){
      System.out.println("I have " + handlersSublist.size() + " handlers for event " + hash); 
      for(EventHandler handler : handlersSublist){
        System.out.println("Fire event " + hash + " to " + handler.getClass().getName().toString());
        event.dispatch((T)handler);
      }
    }
  }

  public <T> void addHandler(Event.Type<T> type, EventHandler handler){
    Integer hash = type.hashCode();
    List<EventHandler> handlersSublist = handlers.get(hash);
    if(handlersSublist == null){
      handlersSublist = new ArrayList<>();
      handlers.put(hash,handlersSublist);
    }
    System.out.println("Add " + handler.getClass().getName().toString() + " for event " + hash);
    handlersSublist.add(handler);
  }

  public <T> void removeHandler(Event.Type<T> type, EventHandler handler) {
    Integer hash = type.hashCode();
    List<EventHandler> handlersSublist = handlers.get(hash);
    if (handlersSublist != null) {
      System.out.println("Remove " + handler.getClass().getName().toString() + " for event " + hash);
      handlersSublist.remove(handler);
    }
  }
}
```

I have an *AEventHandler* which listens to *AEvent*. When an *AEvent* is fired, a given handler does some stuff and removes itself from the eventBus:

```
public class AEventHandlerImpl1 implements AEventHandler
{
  @Override
  public void onAEventReceived(AEvent aEvent)
  {
    //do some stuff...
    //... and remove myself from the bus for AEvent
    EventBus.getInstance().removeHandler(AEvent.TYPE, this);
  }
}
```

In my main method, I create 2 handlers, I add them to the bus to listen to *AEvent* and I fire a *AEvent* event:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("-= START =-");
    //create new handlers
    AEventHandlerImpl1 handler1 = new AEventHandlerImpl1();
    AEventHandlerImpl1 handler2 = new AEventHandlerImpl1();
    //add handlers on the eventBus
    EventBus.getInstance().addHandler(AEvent.TYPE, handler1);
    EventBus.getInstance().addHandler(AEvent.TYPE, handler2);
    //fire event
    EventBus.getInstance().fireEvent(new AEvent());
    //end
    System.out.println("-= END =-");
  }
```

The result is:

```
-= START =-
Add be.test.AEventHandlerImpl1 for event 1
Add be.test.AEventHandlerImpl1 for event 1
I have 2 handlers for event 1
Fire event 1 to be.test.AEventHandlerImpl1
Remove be.test.AEventHandlerImpl1 for event 1
-= END =-
```

The dispatch method is never called for second handler.
It's because the first handler removes itself from the bus (from the handlersSublist) during the loop statement.
I have solved this problem looping on a copy of *handlersSublist*, not on handlersSublist itself.
But the question is, why don't I get a `ConcurrentModificationException`?
I'm modifying an `ArrayList` during looping on it.
In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994277/java-concurrentmodificationexception), user1947415 got a `ConcurrentModificationException` when he removed the first element of the list.
In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673653/why-isnt-this-code-causing-a-concurrentmodificationexception/14673738#14673738), user1699872 didn't get exception because he used an `Iterator` to loop on the list.
What's going on? Why am I not getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` since I'm not using `Iterator` and I remove the first element of list?.

Can someone explain me why?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: I don't see any for cycle... where is the loop that sould throw the concurrentModificationException?

Comment: @Jkike In the `EventBus` class, method `fireEvent`.

Comment: Do you mean the dispatch removes the event in `fireEvent`?

Comment: But you are not removing anything in that loop. If I read correct you are just dispatching the event. The remove part is not in a loop, later you are accessing the object position directly in the array to remove it. So no concurrent access

Comment: @Jkike If I remove the call to `removeHandler()` in `onAEventReceived()` method of the `AEventHandlerImpl1` class and I add handlersSublist.remove(handler) in `fireEvent()` method just after the call to event.dispatch(), I get the same result, no exception.